# How can I open google maps in a popover in my ipad app?

Tags: ios, mapkit, uipopovercontroller

I am unable to figure out how to open google maps in a popover in my ipad app.

Currently all I get is an empty popover and the location opening up in safari.

Here is my code:-

```
MapViewController *map = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
UITableView *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

map.stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q="];
map.stringURL = [map.stringURL stringByAppendingString:[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
map.stringURL = [map.stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:map.stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:map];
popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 250);
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:[cell frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing almost everything right. But you send the url to the wrong object.

In your mapviewcontroller, you can have a UIWebView and set the url of that webview to the URL you just created.

Here, you ask safari to launch and display the maps, indeed exiting your app to do it.

What would even be better, and more Mapkit like, would be to display a mapview instead of a map inside a webview. I advise you to look at the documentation on mapkit and check out the MapCallouts example from Apple which provides a nice overview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, you can simple create your map in a new view controller, then connect the pervious view to your new view with google map with the option "popover". 
Hope can solve your problem.